# tabularx with rotatebox and top-alignment

Tags: tables, rotating, tabularx

I would like to write a table with column name in a rotatebox.

The problem is that I can't make the row title in 2 lines and rotated and then, the content in itemize is not top-aligned.

Can you help me doing what I want.

Here is my code :

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|}
    \hline
     & \textbf{column title1} & \textbf{column title2} \\ 
    \hline 
    \parbox{1cm}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{title1\\ on 2 lines}}}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item content item1 top aligned.
        \item content item2.
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item content item1 top aligned.
        \item content item2.
    \end{itemize} \\ 
    \hline 
     & \textbf{column title1} & \textbf{column title2} \\ 
    \hline
    \parbox{1cm}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{title2\\ on 2 lines}}} 
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item content item1 top aligned.
        \item content item2.
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item content item1 top aligned.
        \item content item2.
    \end{itemize} \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Thanks for your replies.

ps: sorry for my English, I'm a french tex user :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\belowbaseline` command pushes its argument to a distance below the baseline, given by the optional argument.  In this case, I made it 0ex, but you can change that.

The drop of the normally aligned columns, relative to the top of their cells, is due to the itemize environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|}
    \hline
     & \textbf{column title1} & \textbf{column title2} \\ 
    \hline 
    \belowbaseline[0ex]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1.7cm}{%
       \raggedright\textbf{title1\\ on 2 lines}}}}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item content item1 top aligned.
        \item content item2.
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item content item1 top aligned.
        \item content item2.
    \end{itemize} \\ 
    \hline 
     & \textbf{column title1} & \textbf{column title2} \\ 
    \hline
    \belowbaseline[0ex]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1.7cm}{%
      \raggedright\textbf{title2\\ on 2 lines}}}}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item content item1 top aligned.
        \item content item2.
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item content item1 top aligned.
        \item content item2.
    \end{itemize} \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it helped me a little. However, can you add how to make my row title on 2 separated lines please? I tried to do it by adding `\\\`on the title but it did not work ? Why not ? hurtauda

Comment: @user2551001 See revision.  I reversed parbox and rotatebox.  Also, I added extra parbox width to force result onto 2, not three lines.